# Fortran format - problem with numbers < 1e-100

Tags: fortran, format, precision, digits

I'm having a problem when some numbers get to small in my program, because I write them on a file and exponential format gets different:
for example, numbers > 1e-100:
0.3979111076224349D-98
smaller numbers:
0.2306878464709676-101 (The D disappears)

And since it is read by another program, those numbers are not read properly.

Currently I'm using the format 3D25.16
A possible solution would be forcing 3E25.15E3
The problem is that I lose 1 digit for any number

I want to avoid losing a digit, and I want to avoid losing performance with tests before printing.

Is there any other solution? The ideal solution for me would be a format that prints exponential with 2 digits on exponent and change to 3 digit when <1e-100
Other good solution would be a format option that transforms very small numbers into zero

Other doubt is: when changing from 3D25.16 to 3E25.15E3 do I lose precision by changing D to E? Because 3D25.15E3 is not accepted

Thank you

Comment: what about 3E26.15E3

Comment: Why not use `3e26.15e3`?

Comment: Please be advised that you are asking two different questions in one. This is not really how one should ask questions on SO. You might concider to ask two separate questions.

Comment: Possibly best not to ask the separate question about `d` rather than `e`.  However, you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28312619/3157076) about that.

Comment: 'The problem is that I lose 1 digit for any number'. Either you do not care much about storage, and you can add back the extra digit, or you care a lot about space and shouldn't be using ASCII anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everyone said in the comments (and also you in the question), you can just  use `E` descriptor instead of `D`, so you are allowed to specify the number of digits for the exponent part.

> Currently I'm using the format 3D25.16 A possible solution would be forcing 3E25.15E3 The problem is that I lose 1 digit for any number

Well, why not just increase the width of the output with `3E26.15E3`?

> Other doubt is: when changing from 3D25.16 to 3E25.15E3 do I lose precision by changing D to E?

With `3E25.15E3`: yes, you possibly do (1 digit). With `3E26.15E3`: no, you don't.